# Nextjs can't use import variables inside getStaticProps or getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js

This is my first time posting a question. Hello I am new to nextjs and I am using it with django drf and postgres. The problem is I can't use 'js-cookie' in which I imported on top of my profile.js file inside getStaticProps neither getServerSideProps like this:

My import:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
```

My use case inside getStaticProps/getServerSideProps and when I console.log(token) it returns undefined:
[image]

My use case not in getStaticProps or getServerSideProps but it works and it reads the token correctly:

[image]

In addition, it also works if I directly paste the jwt but it is not dynamic and I don't want that like so:

[image]

These are the errors and it returns undefined when I do console.log(token):
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide textual code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a cookie to store data related to the server that you made a request. `js-cookie` will save the cookie to the browser under a name. So when your browser makes another request to the same server, it automatically attaches the cookie to the `req` object.  `getServerSideProps()` receives `context` object.

```
export const getServerSideProps=async (context)=>{
     const token=context.req.headers
      .split(",").
      .find((c) => c.trim().startsWith("jwt")); // looks like you named it "jwt"
// then make the request 

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as well . Though, my profile.js file is not in the '/pages/api/' is it okay or I should move it there?

Comment: @Justine since you are new let me give you a few advice. First do not share code image or error image because if people want to help you, they might wanna copy the code to test. Second you cannot ask multiple questions. You have to focus on one question and try to give as much as information.

Comment: @justine, try to console.log(context.req.headers) in getServerSideProps and see what you have got.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble and thank you so much for the advise. When I console.log(context.req.headers) I get this: 
Cannot read property 'req' of undefined

Comment: I wrote it like this just to test the context:
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ context }) => {
    console.log(context.req.headers)
    return { props : {} }
}

Comment: @justine it should be    async (context )   not    ({ context }). getServerSideProps() takes "context" object. The way you write " ({ context })" telling that "context object" has a property named "context". you are actually passing "context.context to getServerSideProps

Comment: Apparently I solved it just now, I used getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) and got the cookie using req.cookies.jwt. Thank you so much

Comment: @Justine if this answer helped, pls, like and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

`js-cookie` is a browser based solution, it only works in browser environment.

`getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` only runs on the server, they do not have `document.cookie` or anything like that there.

You need to use some library which is able to accept cookie string as an argument. You can get you cookie string from `req.headers.cookie` but only in `getServerSideProps`, you can't use `getStaticProps` because it supposed to generate static pages and it won't have `request` object.

For example, you could use https://github.com/maticzav/nookies, it is made specifically for Next.js

Comment: Tried this one with a relating solution and problem:
https://github.com/maticzav/nookies/issues/255

In a comment it says to use both 'js-cookie' to set cookie and 'nookies' to read the cookie from ctx on server-side. But it still doesn't work for me.

Also, my profile.js file is not in the '/pages/api/' is it okay or I should move it there?